# Wait until a command ends

Tags: java, command, wait

There's a command, that runs an exe, it makes an output and when this command ends,  then I should run the upload(); method.

```
run.command(exe_path, txt_path);
run.start();

TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(20);

upload();
```

How can I replace the static sleep method?

Comment: Hint:  [ProcessBuilder.start()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#start()) returns a Process object.  Follow the link in the javadoc, and look at the methods of the Process class.

Comment: This is too little code to understand the problem exactly. What type has `run`? What types have `exe_path` and `txt_path`?

Comment: @deHaar the types of `exe_path` and `txt_path` are irrelevant, since OP's not lamenting that they can't run the process, just that they don't know how to wait for it to end. But yeah, a bit more code would have helped.

Answer (score 1):

Using a [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), you should be able to call `Process.waitFor()` to wait for the command to finish.

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("foo.exe", "arg1").start();

// handle any input and output
InputStream stdout = p.getInputStream();
OutputStream stdin = p.getOutputStream();
InputStream stderr = p.getErrorStream();

int ret = p.waitFor(); // <- wait for exit
```